# How to develop horizontal bar using css (with float)

Tags: html, css

How to develop horizontal scroll items in css (we must use float). Here is how I tried to do that. But I am not able to get the desired result. And I must not use flexbox because I need to make it supported to IE. I can use only float. Have a look at my code and let me know where I am making the mistake.

```css
.bar {
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 62px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 46px;
  width: calc(12.5% - 8px);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 123, 45, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(211, 246, 250, 1);
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 13px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.day {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.76;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 13px;
}

.date {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
      <div class='bar'}>
        <div>
          <div class='box'}>
            <div class='day'>monday</div>
            <div class='date'>25</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class='box'}>
            <div class='day'>monday</div>
            <div class='date'>25</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class='box'}>
            <div class='day'>monday</div>
            <div class='date'>25</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class='box'}>
            <div class='day'>monday</div>
            <div class='date'>25</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class='box'}>
            <div class='day'>monday</div>
            <div class='date'>25</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class='box'}>
            <div class='day'>monday</div>
            <div class='date'>25</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class='box'}>
            <div class='day'>monday</div>
            <div class='date'>25</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class='box'}>
            <div class='day'>monday</div>
            <div class='date'>25</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: _But I am not able to get the desired result_ what is your expected r esult?

Comment: I need to support horizontal scroll if the elements are more than 7 items

Comment: Now you can exactly see what we need

Comment: Please do not remove the question if your issue is solved, other people might find it useful.

Comment: Post your answer (not in comment) so everyone has this problem can solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use table instead of nested floating elements. that's the way you can guaranty to work your code on IE

```css
.bar {
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 46px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 123, 45, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(211, 246, 250, 1);
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 13px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.day {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.76;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 13px;
}

.date {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class='bar'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='box'>
          <div class='day'>monday</div>
          <div class='date'>25</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='box'>
          <div class='day'>monday</div>
          <div class='date'>25</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='box'>
          <div class='day'>monday</div>
          <div class='date'>25</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='box'>
          <div class='day'>monday</div>
          <div class='date'>25</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='box'>
          <div class='day'>monday</div>
          <div class='date'>25</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='box'>
          <div class='day'>monday</div>
          <div class='date'>25</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='box'>
          <div class='day'>monday</div>
          <div class='date'>25</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='box'>
          <div class='day'>monday</div>
          <div class='date'>25</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```